# Toyota Matrix 2012 Oil Filter Cap becomes extremely tight and hard to open

Tags: corolla, oil-filter, matrix

Toyota Matrix 2012 Oil Filter Cap becomes extremely tight and hard to open
I was working on my Friend’s Toyota Matrix 2012 Oil Change and I encountered a situation with its Special Oil Filter Cap. The cap was excessively tight and it was so difficult to open it. I manage to open the cap, but my finger got injured.

**I used a wrench** and the tool shown in below pictures. It is quite efficent.
[image]

I do member I did not over tightened the cap during the last oil change per instruction on the oil filter. Is there any special technique that I was missing? Why the cap became so tight?

Comment: Hard to open by hand, or hard to open even with your tool and a wrench?

Comment: Just edited the question. I used a wrench.

Comment: They sometimes become tight due to heat cycles (engine cold-hot-cold). This is not abnormal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run into this a lot its a combination of the o-ring and the filter cap bing plastic/rounding off. If you have someone lightly pry against the cap and tap it with a hammer and chisel it usually breaks free.

You should always replace the o ring and apply some clean oil to it when changing the filter

Comment: Would adding an extension to the wrench's arm help or it might cause a damage?

Comment: @AllanXu It helps, but you have to be extra careful. A short piece of tubing will do the trick. Don't hit the wrench arm with anything. You will break the plastic parts.

Comment: you can try it may end up slipping though

Comment: @racefever, I am not following what is "short piece of tubing"?

Comment: @AllanXu He means a piece of steel pipe that slips over the ratchet to gain extra leverage.

Comment: Just asking, should I assume that the use of an impact wrench is not an option here?

Comment: @AllanXu Not unless you have a new oil filter housing cap to replace it if it breaks.

Comment: @AllanXu No, never use an impact wrench on plastic components unless the manual says its safe.

Comment: short piece of tubing to gain extra leverage is aka a 'breaker bar'

Comment: Ok, one last question, does wd-40 help or could cause harm around the oil filter pan?

Comment: @AllanXu WD-40 wouldn't harm anything. are you talking about lubricating the new o-ring? I doubt it would help in removing the stuck filter cap though.